# facing an issue in converting celcius to fahrenhite in python.here is my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, python-requests

```
def cel_to_far(c):
    f=c*9/5+32
    return f
d=input(" enter the celcius scale number:")
print( cel_to_far(d))
```

and here is an issue in my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 5, in <module>
    print( cel_to_far(d))
 line 2, in cel_to_far
    f=c*9/5+32
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string. You need to turn it into a number with either `int()` or `float()`

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function you are using takes the user input and stores it as a string. So, 'd' in your code is referencing a string (even if that string is a number!).

This can be solved by setting the following:

```
d = int(input(" enter the celcius scale number:"))
```

The `int` function converts the number stored in the string to an integer

Answer (score 0):

If you are bothered about more precision you should go for `float` instead.

`d = float(input(" enter the celcius scale number:"))`